# Regex: Ignore the first match of continuous same characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to ignore the first `\` in a string in a continuous sequence by using regex. So that when there is only `\`, we will not match it. When there are two `\\`, we only match one `\`.

For example:

I got:

```
{\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/p1.pstatp.com\\/origin\\/tuchong.fullscreen\\/29016715_tt\"}
```

what regex I can use to make it become:

```
{"url":"http:\/\/p1.pstatp.com\/origin\/tuchong.fullscreen\/29016715_tt"}
```

How to make this happen?

Comment: So? I don't see a single question mark in your "question". What is the question? What have you tried? What happened? What became the problem? What do you suspect is causing the problem? Be sure to check your post carefully to ensure you have all required information to get yourself an answer.

Comment: @DanielCheung Sorry to make you confused. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should suit your needs :

```
(?<!\\)\\
```

See this [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lZ7Oey/1/).